# Motherboard power LED goes on but quickly goes off, with a "tumble" sound, and this goes on in cycles, while nothing else happens

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Laptop Toshiba Satellite L850-1V7
Power LED goes on but quickly goes off, with a "tumble" sound, and this goes on in cycles, while nothing else happens.
A video of it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13dR7WQ_6y-RySQCyqYUWP1oioxTrJcU5/view?usp=sharing

I bought a new motherboard and a new CPU and everything is still the same.
I tried a different power source, but the same happens. The laptop requires 19V. The power sources measure ~20V and 21V.
I tried to disconnect every connector and simply connect the power to the motherboard, and still, the same happens.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLzBM.jpg)

Comment: Is the power source the same in both instances? Did you measure it under load? [measuring voltage under true load is usually beyond the ability of the home user. Poking it with a voltmeter does not do it.] I'd recommend taking it to a professional, rather than make any more expensive guesses.

Comment: The power source is the same, yes. No, I did not measure it under load. What does it mean, this type of LED+sound behavior, almost as if trying to power up something, but constantly "giving up"?

Comment: Take it to a professional. If you can't measure it under load, you have no idea if the PSU is still good. You already spent money on a motherboard & processor that you probably  didn't need. Try to avoid any more expensive guesswork.