# Motherboard power LED goes on but quickly goes off, with a “tumble” sound, and this goes on in cycles, while nothing else happens

Tags: cpu-usage, laptop

Laptop Toshiba Satellite L850-1V7 Power LED goes on but quickly goes off, with a "tumble" sound, and this goes on in cycles, while nothing else happens. A video of it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13dR7WQ_6y-RySQCyqYUWP1oioxTrJcU5/view?usp=sharing

I bought a new motherboard and a new CPU and everything is still the same. I tried a different power source, but the same happens. The laptop requires 19V. The power sources measure ~20V and 21V. I tried to disconnect every connector and simply connect the power to the motherboard, and still, the same happens.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3dRw.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Motherboard power LED goes on but quickly goes off, with a "tumble" sound, and this goes on in cycles, while nothing else happens](https://superuser.com/questions/1577233/motherboard-power-led-goes-on-but-quickly-goes-off-with-a-tumble-sound-and-t)

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer his question, but it's the exact same question so when that one is answered it will also answer this one.

Comment: @user253751 When a question is posted twice it's normal to mark the second post as a duplicate of the first. The OP can also delete the second post, but I don't think he has been back recently.

Comment: @MichaelHampton However, the automatically generated comment says "Does this answer your question?". Asking whether your own question answers your own question is a dumb question.

Comment: @user253751 Oh I agree about that! But I didn't write the automatically generated comment.

Comment: ...Anyway. I'm still without any clue about what it could be.